# How to call updateProfile() after creating User

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set the `.displayName` property of a user, right after it is created.

The Problem:
The user needs some time to get created, so it would not work to use `.updateProfile()` right after calling `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. So how can I eventually update the `.displayName` right after the creation?

Right now I am trying this way:

```
export function signup(currentUser, email, password) {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    updateProfile(currentUser, {displayName : "some name"})   
}
```

When I am calling the function I use this function for the value of `currentUser`

```
export function useAuth() {
    const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => setCurrentUser(user));
        return unsub; // Cleaning Function
    }, [])

    return currentUser;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the implementation of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` looks like, but have you looked into async/await?
https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and `updateProfile()` methods are **asynchronous** and return a Promise. Therefore you either need to [chain the Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) or use `async/await` as mentioned by Scott in his comment.

**1/ Chain the Promises**

```
export function signup(currentUser, email, password) {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(userCredential => {
       updateProfile(userCredential.user, {displayName : "some name"})   
    })
}
```

**2/ Use `async/await`**

```
export async function signup(currentUser, email, password) {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    await updateProfile(userCredential.user, {displayName : "some name"})   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `updateProfile(currentUser, {displayName : currentUser.displayName})` after currentUser have been updated by the useAuth hook

```js
useEffect(() =>{
   if ('userName' in currentUser && currentUser.userName !== '') {
    updateProfile(currentUser, {displayName : currentUser.userName})  
   }
}, [currentUser])
```